# How to use INNER JOIN with array on second table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I can't properly use INNER JOIN. This is the actual return output via json on php.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "itinerary_customer_id": "856",
        "datetime_created": "2020-04-20 19:54:16",
        "documents": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "itinerary_id": "1",
                "datetime_created": "2020-04-20 22:51:12"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "itinerary_id": "1",
                "datetime_created": "2020-04-20 22:51:12"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "itinerary_customer_id": "857",
        "datetime_created": "2020-04-20 19:54:16",
        "documents": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "itinerary_id": "2",
                "datetime_created": "2020-04-20 22:51:12"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "itinerary_id": "2",
                "datetime_created": "2020-04-20 22:51:12"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Its look like array json and there's possible array inside each data.
Here's my existing code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM itinerary INNER JOIN itinerary_documents ON itinerary_documents.itinerary_id = itinerary.id WHERE itinerary_customer_id = '".$customer_id."' ";
    $result = $mysql->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $item = $row;
            $json = json_encode($item);
        }
    }else{
        $item = array("error"=> true, "message"=> "No Itinerary found.");
        $json = json_encode($item);
    }

echo $json;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks. Can you check it again? @abestrad

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Instead always name (and properly qualify) only the columns you actually want returned. Fix that, and then get back to us.

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Comment: This looks dodgy: `while ($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $item = $row;
            $json = json_encode($item);
        }` ... you are pushing the fetched row into the `$row` array then into `$item` (overwriting it each time), then `json_encoding()` `$item` (on each iteration), then overwriting `$json` every iteration.   ...Maybe you'd just like to `fetchall()` and json_encode it just once.